# Contradictory results while comparing O(n) and O(logn) program for finding largest number in an array using python?

Tags: python, arrays, max, array-algorithms

I was comparing the two algorithm for finding the largest number in an array. I made two functions named as max1, max2.

**max1(arr)**: This function is a time complexity **O(n)** function which traverses the whole array to find the largest element.

**max2(arr,start,end)**: This function does the splitting of the array into two halves recursively in order to find the largest number. Hence it's time complexity is **O(log n)**.

As far as the time complexity is concerned the **max2** function should take lesser time compared to **max1** function. But for my surprise, **the results are contradicting my assumptions**.

[image]

Here is the following code:

```
def max1(arr):
    mx = float('-inf')
    for i in arr:
        if mx < i:
            mx = i
    return mx


def max2(arr,start,end):
    if start == end:
        return arr[start]
    else:
        mid = (start + end)//2
        return max(max2(arr,start,mid),max2(arr,mid+1,end))


import time
from random import randint
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
sns.set()

def getData():
    n = 100
    N = []
    b = []
    c = []
    while n < 1000000:
        x = [randint(0,50) for i in range(n)]

        t1 = time() 
        max1(x)
        t2 = time()
        b.append(t2 - t1)

        t1 = time() 
        max2(x,0,n-1)
        t2 = time()
        c.append(t2 - t1)

        N.append(n)
        n += 10000
        print('*',end = '')

    return N,b,c

def analyse(N,b,c):
    plt.plot(N,b, label = 'max1')
    plt.plot(N,c, label = 'max2')
    plt.xlabel('Amount of data', fontsize = 20)
    plt.ylabel('Time taken', fontsize = 20)
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()

# results
# b => max1
# c => max2
N,b,c = getData()
analyse(N,b,c)
```

If there is any error in my assumptions, kindly correct me? or If I am right, then how is this contradiction happening?

Comment: `max2` is an inefficient O(n), not O(log n). You can’t find the maximum of an array in arbitrary order in better than O(n) time. `max2` is parallelizable, though.

Comment: Doesn't the splitting cause it go O(log n)?

Comment: No, because you’re doing work on both sides of the split. If you knew which side the max was on each time and only chose to look recursively in that one, you could do it in O(log n).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I understood my mistake. So is the time complexity of max2 O(n log n) just like merge sort's? I just took a look here. https://medium.com/karuna-sehgal/a-simplified-explanation-of-merge-sort-77089fe03bb2

Comment: totally unrelated but you certainly want to learn about the stdlib's `timeit` module

Comment: No, it’s O(n). Merge sort is O(n log n) because it does work on each element (of which there are n) for each level of the call stack (of which there are O(log n)). Binary search is O(log n) because it does a constant amount of work (O(1)) for each level of the call stack (O(log n)). `max2` does O(n / 2^l) work for each level of the call stack if l = 0 is the level where `start == end` and it goes up from there, which adds up to O(n) because the sum of 1/2^l for l from 0 to any value (in this case ~ log n) is at least 1/2 and less than 2. O(1/2 n) = O(2n) = O(n)